# How can I group a pandas dataframe by time with a minimal amount of rows for each group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this;

```
    created_at         value1    value2    value3
2021-04-25 11:38:33      1          1        5
2021-04-25 11:38:47      4          3        6   
2021-04-25 11:39:36      1          1        8   
2021-04-25 11:39:47      6          5        5   
2021-04-25 11:40:50      8          7        3
```

I am trying to create groups with the mean values within timeframes of 2 minutes.

I am using the following code;

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='2Min')]).mean())
```

This works but at the moment I am trying to add a requirement that the Grouper needs at least 20 rows within that timeframe in order to aggregate the mean values but I can't find a solution to this.

Comment: What will be the expected output if the group has less than 20 rows? Do you want drop those groups/rows?

Comment: yes I would like to drop the rows @ShubhamSharma

Answer (score 2):

One-liner:

```py
df.groupby(
    [pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='2Min')]
).agg(
    lambda x: x.mean() if len(x) > 20 else None  # get None if there are not at least 20 rows in the group
).dropna(
    how='all', axis=0  # remove all the rows with all na values
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to first calculate the `mean` then drop the groups in the aggregate frame using boolean indexing which have less than `20` rows.

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='2Min'))
avg = g.mean()[g.size() >= 20]
```

**Alternative approach** with `transform` which first filters the valid groups (i.e. groups which have at least 20 rows) then aggregate the filtered groups using `mean`

```
g = pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='2Min')
m = df.groupby(g)['value1'].transform('size').ge(20)
avg = df[m].groupby(g).mean()
```